# callbacks google chrome extension

Tags: callback, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a Google Chrome Extension (and learning an awful lot in the process).  Callback functions are something of a mystery.  I started researching the subject to solve a problem from an earlier question I posted and found a post from @serg containing a model I could use.  Here is the solution:

```
function getKeyWords(action, callback){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(
            {
                cmd: action
            },
            function(response)
            {
                callback(response.keyWordsFound);
            }
    );
}

var keyWords="";
getKeyWords("sendKeyWords", function(reply) {
    keyWordList=reply;

    for (var i = 0; i<keyWordList.length; ++i)
    {
        keyWords=keyWords+" "+keyWordList[i];
    }
    msgComment1.innerHTML="<strong>"+keyWords+"</strong>";
    console.log("Reply is:", keyWords);
});
```

Now I want to extend this solution but this time the function has to return two arguments instead of one.  I modified the code above the best I could understand it but it fails.  Here is the modified code:

```
function getFacePageDat(action, callback){
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(
            {
                cmd: action
            },
            function(response)
            {
                callback(response.ageList, response.seekList);
            }
    );
}

getFacePageDat("sendSearchPageInfo", function(reply1, reply2) {
    profileAgeCityMetro=reply1;
    profileSeeks=reply2;
    alert("Reply is:", profileAgeCityMetro+" seeks "+profileSeeks);
    console.log("Reply is:", profileAgeCityMetro+" seeks "+profileSeeks);
});
```

Unfortunately this fails on "Error in event handler for 'undefined': TypeError: Property 'log' of object # is not a function.  I know the answer to this question is rather simple if you have a grasp of callbacks but I don't.  Any help out there?

Comment: Your code looks correct (well besides that alert with comma), the problem must be somewhere elase.

Comment: Find which line the error is at and you will then know what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

*Serg is likely correct above:*

console.log("Reply is:", profileAgeCityMetro+" seeks "+profileSeeks);

*should be*

console.log("Reply is:" + profileAgeCityMetro + " seeks " + profileSeeks);